# modification of a component's object before displaying it into structural directive *ngFor

Tags: angular

I am working on a simple example of Angular basics in which it is necessary to display through one component the list of another one.

The item component has an object as property named `post` and I would like to access attributes when instantiating my item component in my list component.

I thought I had found a solution but now what I cannot do is add item instances into my list component without modifying my item's post attributes... one step forward two steps back.

I tried assigning the object's attributes directly from the constructor passing string variables. However, at this point I met an error at the line of my DOM item selector where I display the list of my item with an `ngFor`. It says that there was no provider for string - so I tried adding `provider:[String]` into the item component but this resulted in another error.

Now I pass empty string values to my item's object from the constructor and I created a method to change it from outside the component.

The problem is when I push my instantiated item into my item's array, modified with new string values passed to my method, the display of my items shows them with empty strings - whereas the `console.log(item)` shows them with modified attributes.

Here is my actual code within the two components:

**Item component:**

```js
export class PostListItemComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  public post: {
    title: string;
    content: string;
    loveIts: number;
    created_at: Date;
  };

  constructor() {
    const title = "";
    const content = "";
    const created_at = new Date();
    const loveIts = 0;
    this.post = { title, content, loveIts, created_at };
  }

  addContent(title: string, content: string) {
    const created_at = new Date();
    const loveIts = 0;
    this.post = { title, content, created_at, loveIts };
    return this.post;
  }
```

**list component:**

```js
export class PostListComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  public items: Array<PostListItemComponentComponent>;
  constructor() {
    this.items = [];
  }

  addItem() {
    const title = "hohoho";
    const content = "hehehe";
    const item = new PostListItemComponentComponent();
    item.addContent(title, content);
    this.items.push(item);
    console.log(this.items);
  }
}
```

I just expect the DOM display to be my list of items with "hohoho" and "hehehe" into the `<p></p>` tags. However it stays empty.

Any help is welcome.

I'm new to Stack Overflow, so sorry if my asking isn't summarized or explicit enough.

---

**Edit:**

Below is my list component html file

```html
<button (click)="addItem()">add article</button>
<ul>
  <app-post-list-item-component *ngFor="let item of items" ></app-post-list-item-component>
</ul>
```

Comment: it's a clasic parent-child, you need use a `@Input` in your child component, see https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction